# how can you compare two strings punctuation insensitively?

Tags: c, string-comparison

I am busy making a spell checker and when I compare the word **I'm** to the dictionary version **im** it returns false. I used `strcasecmp` to compare them case insensitively but the apostrophe is still a problem. How can I compare the two (punctuation insensitively) and get true as the output?

Comment: You need to write your own routine to compare characters in both strings and skip any punctuation.

Comment: okay thanks, I thought I had to do that but I just wanted to check and see if there was an easier way and google wasn't really helpful.

Comment: When I wrote my spellchecker, I put words like "I'm" and "don't" in my dictionary *with their apostrophes*.  If you do a "punctuation insensitive" string comparison between, say, "don't" and "dont", that means your spellchecker will also accept misspellings like "dont" and "d'ont".  ("im" is not a dictionary word, either.)

Comment: Thanks Steve, I realised that a bit earlier and I saw that I have a problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own routine to skip punctuation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int insenistive_strcmp(char const* s1, char const* s2)
{
    unsigned char const* p1 = (unsigned char const*)s1;
    unsigned char const* p2 = (unsigned char const*)s2;

    for (;; ++p1, ++p2)
    {
        while (ispunct(*p1))
            ++p1;

        while (ispunct(*p2))
            ++p2;
        
        int ch1 = toupper(*p1);
        int ch2 = toupper(*p2);

        if (!ch1 || !ch2 || ch1 != ch2)
            return ch1 - ch2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", insenistive_strcmp("I'm", "im"));
}
```